# Magento 2 How to add custom CSS to HTML Template?

Tags: magento2, layout, css

I have a custom html template where I have classes.

On layout I have added my css like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/application.css" />
    </head>
    <body> 
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Application\Block\Main" name="application_send" template="Vendor_Application::application.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>    
    </body>
</page>
```

And inside PHTML i'm using a javascript component in order to render html template

Just like this:

```
 <div id="port-form" data-bind="scope:'port-form'">
      <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
      <!-- ko template: template2--><!-- /ko -->
      <!-- ko template: template3 --><!-- /ko -->
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#port-form": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                  "components": {
                        "port-form": {
                            "component": "Vendor_Application/js/port-app-form",
                            "quote_data": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $data ?>,
                            "quantities": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $quantities ?>
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
```

It's not taking any effect

I get this error:

```
Refused to apply style from '.../en_US/css/application.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled
```

Greetings

Comment: Where exactly is your CSS file placed?

Comment: You can change  : <css src="css/application.css" /> to <css src="Vendor_Application::css/application.css" />

Comment: @MichałBiarda my css is under web/css/application.css

Comment: @nhungoduc it did not work

Comment: have you cleared magento cache if so maybe your css part is wrong or maybe your browser cache

Comment: yes, I have clared Cache and even ran php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy , also tried to add it inside css/source/_module.less and did not work either.

Comment: maybe this doesn't work all the time but i've had a few times like that ==> can't update the code , or modify it ==> run setup:upgrade , deploy but it doesn't work and i delete the file and that folder go use the deleted file and folder and work again as usual

Comment: rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* && rm -rf var/view_preprocessed && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: ... I usually run this command because sometimes just running php bin/magento s:s:d -f can't update the modification in app/code

Answer (score 0):

please add css under app/code/Vendor/Module/view/web/css and add in xml like

```
 <css src="Vendor_Module::css/application.css" />
```

Comment: I'm not using a theme, I'm using it into a module

Comment: Answer updated.